# Find the largest sequence of five numbers in a string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, string

HI everyone hopefully an  easy one. I have split a string example below in to 5 digit blocks I now need to find the largest 5 number sequence, and not sure how to do this any help much appreciated.    "731671765313306249192251196744265747423553491949349698352036854250632623957831801698480186947885184385861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511125406987471585238630507156932909632952274430435576689664895

```
function solution(digits){


let output =  digits.match(/.{1,5}/g);
console.log(output);

}
```

Comment: please add the wanted result.

Comment: What if the greatest 5 digit number starts at index 2 -- and you have split obviously at index 5, 10, 15, ... but not 2.

Comment: You'll need to loop, one character at at time and check from that character to the next 4 after it, not just from 1-5, 6-10, 11-15, etc.

Answer (score 3):

This approach (of splitting into chunks of 5), will not always give the optimal result, as you are not looking at every possible chunk of 5... only those that start at an index that is a multiple of 5.

So just iterate through every array index, and then take 5 characters from there, and compare...

```js
let str = "731671765313306249192251196744265747423553491949349698352036854250632623957831801698480186947885184385861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511125406987471585238630507156932909632952274430435576689664895";

let best = "";
for (let i = 5; i <= str.length; i++) {
    let slice = str.slice(i - 5, i);
    if (slice > best) best = slice;
}

console.log(best);
```